# There is a Jpanel that opens when running from eclipse and after exporting as executable jar it won't open

Tags: java

I'm creating a game called lines of Actions and I facing a problem here when exporting to executable jar file

[image: http://s21.postimg.org/rk1jef9wn/Untitled.png]

When I press the Button "Two Players" this Panel should be shown

[image: http://s21.postimg.org/dvcclaz8n/Untitled.png]

and it does show when I run it from eclipse but it doesn't when I run the executable jar file

Note: the images are in the images source folder
and I'm using this method to get an image:

```
private ImageIcon image(String s) {
    return new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(s));
}
```

and when creating a Jlable :

```
new Jlabel(image("example.png"));
```

while the project is like this:

[image: http://s14.postimg.org/lkuqvzut9/Untitled.png]

Comment: So you want us to read your mind to find your code?

Comment: no but I thought it could be a problem while exporting

Comment: Well how did you export it? Again, we can't magically know how.

Comment: I think your pc doesn't really like the game and denies executing it.

Comment: Make sure you're including your images when you build the jar file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the jar from console `java -jar filename.jar`. You most likely have null on some of your resources (images).

You can see the errors and warnings in the console, clicking the jar won't let you do that.

To your comment below: Try loading the image for the JPanel the same way you are loading the main background images (for your title/options menu), that we know to work already. You need an `inputstream` for loading resources within your executable `.jar`.

[getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) is what you want to use for loading resources from within executables. For good practice always use this, even within your IDE ( eclipse) as exporting will be much easier.

To your question edit: `getResource` returns an `URL` which happens to be `null` in this case. Try doing `image("example.png"));`. You wrote `.ong` as the fileextension, if you meant `.png` change that and your code should work :)

If you didn't mean to write `.ong` then try adding a backslash to your filename like so: `image("/example.png");` you can read in the link above why.

Comment: *"You can see the errors and warnings in the console.."*  ..as long as the code does not ignore exceptions by catching & ignoring them. +1

Comment: Yes there is a NullPointerException could you till me what to change in my code to load the images correctly

Comment: You should add the exception and relevant parts of the stack trace to your question first

Comment: One of the problems The problem was:
There an image called "Back.png" and I called it by "back.png"
it seems that when running eclipse it isn't case sensitive and when running from the executable jar it is case sensitive and I don't know why :D

Comment: .jar files are casesensitive